# Python. Создать словарь из списка, в котором пары "ключ-значение" будут уникальными

Tags: python

Входные данные:
Список фамилий. Фамилии в списке уникальные.

Выходные данные:
Словарь, содержащий пары из фамилий. Пары "Фамилия 1 - Фамилия 2" уникальны, то есть ни одна из фамилий в паре не повторяется в других парах.

"Бизнес"-смысл:
Создать генератор для игры в тайного Санту.

Какой алгоритм я взял за основу:
1. Проверка элемента из списка в словаре на позиции ключа или значения. Если элемент есть - переходим к следующему.
2. Если элемента нет - находим рандомную фамилию из списка. Если фамилия совпадает с проверяемой фамилией ИЛИ найденная фамилия есть в одной из пар словаря - ещё раз ищем фамилию.
3. Если фамилия уникальна - добавляем пару из проверяемой и найденной фамилии в словарь и переходим дальше.

Что я не могу сделать:
1. Проверить наличие проверяемой фамилии не только в ключе словаря, но и в значении.
2. Сделать цикл поиска рандомной фамилии. Не понимаю, как обозначить условие, которое заново запускает рандомайзер.

Код, до которого дошёл я:

```
import random

colleagues = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E', 'F', 'G']


ThiefSanta = {}
pair = []
for colleague in colleagues:
    if colleague in ThiefSanta.items():
        continue
else:
    if random.choice(colleagues) == colleague:
         continue;
    else:
        friend = random.choice(colleagues)
        pair.append(colleague)
        pair.append(friend)
    ThiefSanta.update([pair])
    pair.clear()
print(ThiefSanta)
```

Прошу помощи!

Answer (score 2):

На просторах интернета найдено решение:

```
import random

colleagues = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E', 'F', 'G']

random.shuffle(colleagues)
offset = [colleagues[-1]] + colleagues[:-1]
for santa, receiver in zip(colleagues, offset):
     print(santa, "buys for", receiver)
```